# Error while mocking EF calls

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, rhino-mocks

I have just started using Rhino mocks and I am having difficulty doing that.

Here is my function which I am trying to test.

```
public bool IsUserExists(string emailAddress)
{
    return _repository.IsUserExists(emailAddress);
}
```

Here is my test which I wrote and currently failing when the actual call is made

```
[TestClass]
public class UserServiceTest
{
    private MockRepository _mockRepository;
    private IUserRepository _userRepository; 
    private IUserService _userService;
    public UserServiceTest()
    {
         _mockRepository = new MockRepository();
        _userRepository = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IUserRepository>();
        _userAccntService = new UserAccntService();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Should_return_true_IfUserWithEmailExists()
    {
        var emailaddress = "noreply@abc.com";

        _userRepository.Stub(x => x.IsUserExists(emailaddress)).Return(true);

        bool ifUserExists = _userAccntService.IsUserAcctExists(emailaddress); //    throws!

        Assert.AreEqual(ifUserExists,true);

    }
}
```

We are currently using EF for making repository calls.
And when I am trying to test this method it is failing when the function call is made in actual.
I am getting entitycommandexecution error in the call to `_userAccntService.IsUserAcctExists`.

Comment: how is `_userRepository` created?

Comment: where are you injecting `_userRepository` into `_userAccntService`? How are you creating `_userAccntService`? You need a complete sample.

Comment: @Adam: I have updated the question,sorry about that

Comment: I would highly recommend you to use something else than Rhino Mocks. There is nothing wrong with it (I've used it in several projects) but mocking frameworks like NSubstitute or FakeItEasy have much easier learning curve and easier syntax to work with. I'm only suggesting this because you said you have just started to use Rhino mocks. No point switching to another if you have hundreds of tests.

Comment: @ToniParviainen - I struggled and struggled to learn Rhino - I started when the AAA syntax just came out, so a lot of stuff google was showing me was using record replay.  Oh the hours I wasted!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you're getting an entity framework error means that `_repository` is pointing to an actual instance of an EF object, while `_userRepository` is a mock.  Make sure that your `_userAccntService`'s repository instance is pointing to exactly `_userRepository`.

In other words, in your test setup method, when you construct `_userRepository`, make sure **that's** what gets passed into your `_userAccntService` constructor.

---

So, looking at your updated code:

```
public UserServiceTest() {
     _mockRepository = new MockRepository();
    _userRepository = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IUserRepository>();
    _userAccntService = new UserAccntService();
}
```

`_userAccntService` is never passed `_userRepository`, so how can it be expected to use it when you call `IsUserAcctExists()`?  This repository dependency needs to be **injected** into your `_userAccntService` instance.  Something like:

```
public UserServiceTest() {
     _mockRepository = new MockRepository();
    _userRepository = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IUserRepository>();
    _userAccntService = new UserAccntService(_userRepository);
}
```

Comment: you were absolutely correct. It fixed my error now and test passed :)

Comment: @alice7 - woot!  Glad to help :)